# AdMob Ads Not Showing/Can't Enter Payment Details?

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I'm trying to use Admob ads in my iOS App. I have the ad units, ids, I've tested that the views work with test Ids, etc, but I can't get any actual ads in the real app.

On Admob's website, it says they can't serve ads until I've entered payment information, but every time I try to enter it, I get an error page that looks like this (I've also read that you can't enter payment info until you've earned $10)

[image]

Does anyone know what's going on/if there's any other reason ads might not show?

Comment: have you try different browser? or incognito mode?

Comment: I think incognito mode might've worked. I set up an Adsense account (in conjunction to the Admob account?) and it needs to be verified for a day or so, so maybe that's something? I tried in Safari and it still didn't load

Comment: @KelvinTan creating an Adsense account in incognito worked! thank you for the help